# Clear the navigation stack for two graphs at once

Tags: java, android, kotlin, navigation, android-architecture-navigation

I have 3 navigation graphs combined with the Navigation Extension. I need to move from a fragment of one graph to another, without the possibility of returning, so to speak, clear the stack. I added `app:popUpTo="@id/nav_graph" app:popUpToInclusive="true"`, '' to the transition, but this code removes the stack for only one graph, leaving the other and when pressed, it still returns back. Is there any way to clear the stack of two graphs at once upon transition

**link to Navigation Extension https://github.com/android/architecture-components-samples/blob/master/NavigationAdvancedSample/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/navigationadvancedsample/NavigationExtensions.kt**

Answer (score 0):

Use NavOptions.Builder()

XML code not working for me

```
NavOptions.Builder().setPopUpTo(R.id.xxxFragment,true).build()
```